# Comparing regression coefficients with different units?

Tags: regression

I have one regression equation describing the relationship between interest rate i and interest rate c, and another regression equation describing the relationship between house purchase volume and interest rate c.

The coefficient for interest rate i for the regression between interest rate i and interest rate c is 0.5. So, a 1% increase in interest rate i translates to a 0.5% increase in interest rate c.

The coefficient for home purchase volume for the regression between home purchase volume and interest rate c is 0.0000001. So, a $10,000,000 increase in home purchase volume translates to a 1% increase in interest rate c.

How would one determine which variable, home purchase volume or interest rate i, has a stronger effect on interest rate c? I can’t seem to make sense of this due to the different units. If both independent variables were interest rates, then we could simply compare the magnitude of the coefficients and determine the larger coefficient impacts interest rate c to a greater extent.

Comment: This problem be mitigated if you standardized your variables. In that case, you could meaningfully do the comparison you describe.

Comment: How could I forget... thank you.

Comment: See Journal of Applied Statistics, Volume 46, 2019 - Issue 12, Feb 2019.
"Simple and flexible Bayesian inferences for standardized regression coefficients,"
Pages 2254-2288.  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02664763.2019.1584609?journalCode=cjas20